# AngularJS directives require parent not working

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 directives that I want to share functions between, so I figured I would create a parent directive.
I did it like this:

```
.directive('kdAlert', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {

            // Set our dismiss to false
            scope.dismiss = false;

            // Have to use a watch because of issues with other directives
            scope.$watch(function () {

                // Watch the dismiss
                return scope.dismiss;

                // If the value changes
            }, function (dismiss) {

                // If our value is false
                if (dismiss === false || dismiss === 'false') {

                    // Remove the class from the element
                    element.removeClass('ng-hide');

                    // Else, if the value is true (or anything else)
                } else {

                    // Add the class to the element
                    element.addClass('ng-hide');
                }
            });

            // Get our buttons
            var buttons = element.find('button');

            // Binds our close button
            self.bindCloseButton = function (callback) {

                // If we have a button
                for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

                    // Get our current button
                    var button = angular.element(buttons[i]);

                    // If our button is the close button
                    if (button.hasClass('close')) {

                        // If the button is clicked
                        button.on('click', function (e) {

                            console.log('clicked');

                            // Prevent any default actions
                            e.preventDefault();

                            // Callback
                            callback()

                            // Remove our element
                            element.remove();
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
})

.directive('cookie', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'kdAlert',
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/directives/cookie.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {

            // Dismiss the alert
            scope.dismissAlert = function () {

                // Set our cookie
                scope.dismiss = $cookies.dismissCookieAlert = true;
            };

            // Bind our close button
            scope.bindCloseButton(scope.dismissAlert);
        }
    };
})

.directive('newsletter', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'kdAlert',
        controller: 'NewsletterController',
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/directives/newsletter.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {

            // Saves our email address
            scope.subscribe = function (valid) {

                // If we are not valid
                if (!valid) {

                    // Return from the function
                    return;
                }

                // Subscribe
                controller.subscribe(scope.email);
            };

            // Dismiss the alert
            self.dismissAlert = function () {

                // Set our cookie
                self.dismiss = $cookies.dismissNewsletterAlert = true;
            };

            // Bind our close button
            scope.bindCloseButton(scope.dismissAlert);
        }
    };
})
```

The newsletter has a controller also, which just looks like this:

```
.controller('NewsletterController', ['$q', '$cookies', 'SubscriberService', 'toastr', function ($q, $cookies, service, toastr) {
    var self = this;

    // Saves our email address
    self.subscribe = function (email) {

        // Create our deferred promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Subscribe
        service.subscribe(email).success(function () {

            // If we succeed, display a message
            toastr.success('You will now recieve occasional newsletters.');

            // Resolve our promise
            deferred.resolve();
        });

        // Return our promise
        return deferred.promise;
    };
}])
```

but when I run my application I get an error:

> > Controller 'kdAlert', required by directive 'newsletter', can't be found!

does anyone know how I can get it to work?

Comment: You would need to prefix `^` in the required directive name, i.e `require: '^kdAlert',` inorder for it to specify parent requirement. Also you would need a controller as well for `kdAlert` directive inorder to `require` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify `require: 'kdAlert',` to `require: '^kdAlert',` and add a `controller` to your `kdAlert` in order to make the require work, `require` will try to find the controller of the `kdAlert` directive and pass it as a parameter to the directive `link` function.